# JS, JQuery and Observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, rxjs, observable

I`m building third party application for specific sites with Jquery.

Recently I started to use rx.Observable in my project. However, I found to use of this new JS library sometimes is hard to understand. I have tried to convert next peace of code to use with Observables, but it is not working at all;

```
class EventsUtils {

    constructor() {       
        this.observable = Rx.Observable;      
    }
    bindUserLeavePageEvent() {
        var self = this;
        document.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
            $JQ(document).trigger('mouseleave.mo');
        }, false);
            /*We cannot remove document mouse over event thus we trigger Jquery registered custom event and on remove we cancel it*/
        $JQ(document).off('mouseleave.mo').on('mouseleave.mo', (e) => {
            if (e.clientY < 0 && !self.loaded) {
                console.log('loading from screen Leave');
                $JQ('.fixed-button').trigger('click');
                self.loaded = true;                
            }
        });
}
```

$JQ variable is came from jquery.noConflict due to i am running not on my page.
  To convert second expression to Observable I have tried to use next statement:

```
this.observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseleave.mo').pluck('currentTarget').subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
}
```

But without success.
How to convert above event statements to use with Observable and what is common pattern to do this;

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any ?

Comment: No errors, just no logs on console

Comment: The `this.observable` irritates me a little, how exactly are you importing/accessing RxJS or in other words: where and how is `this.observable` being set?

Comment: I update the code of the question. And as for the importing the rxjs it is simple script tag from cdnjs

Comment: Okay, that seems fine - it just looks very weired ;)

Comment: So U think it should work? I will rephrase  - Does Jquery triggers trigger Observers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if `jquery.trigger` does not really work with custom events - you can only catch those events through `$(elem).on` as they are handles internally for browser-compatibility-reasons. (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2476)

But you can relatively easy dispatch custom events (unless you want to target IE<=8)

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  console.log("Original event: Leave");
  
  // dispatching custom events with vanilla-js (should work all the way down to IE9)
  const event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
  event.initEvent("mo.leave", true, true);
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
});

Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document, "mo.leave")
  .pluck("currentTarget")
  .subscribe(target => console.info("Target is", target.nodeName));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks man. And there is away to convert also document.addEventListener with rx.fromEventPattern()?

Comment: you could use `bindCallback` (or `fromCallback` in rxjs4)